# Java socket issue with client and server

Tags: java, sockets, client, inputstream, bufferedreader

I am having an issue comparing the string that is sent from the client to the server.  I am trying to read in the message "HELLO" from the client and then respond with hello back from the server.  My issue is that when I get to my if statement in the server class I am always hitting the else.  I believe I am having trouble understanding which lines are collecting data or just printing.  Going to do some research in the mean time, I want to learn this good.  Any idea as to why, thank you in advance?

Server class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Server myServer = new Server();
        myServer.run();
    }

    public void run() throws Exception
    {

        //Initializes the port the serverSocket will be on
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4200);
            System.out.println("The Server is waiting for a client on port 4200");
        //Accepts the connection for the client socket
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

        InputStreamReader ir = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ir);
        String message = br.readLine();
        //Confirms that the message was received
        System.out.println(message);

            if(message == "HELLO")
            {
                PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                ps.println("Received our hello message.");
            }
            else
            {
                PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                ps.println("Did not receive your hello message");
            }
    }

}
```

Client class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Client myClient = new Client();
        myClient.run();
    }

    public void run() throws Exception
    {
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket("cmps329.csit.selu.edu", 4200);
        //Sends message to the server
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        ps.println("HELLO");
        //Reads and displays response from server
        InputStreamReader ir = new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ir);
        String message = br.readLine();
        System.out.println(message);        
    }

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
if (message.equals("HELLO"))
```

See [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java/513839#513839) for the why.

Comment: perfect lol, such an easy thing to miss thank you.  Would you also know if I am able to use a Scanner to read in command line?  So instead of the client automatically sending the message I would be able to enter in HELLO?... will mark as answer when timer is up

Comment: You can use arguments to a main method, unless the client is supposed to stay running.

Comment: Ahh keeping it running is what I need to look into.  Thanks for your help again sir.